# Чтение String из другого класса

Tags: java, строки

Есть программа на java, которая читает из файла текст и выводит на экран. Я хочу запихнуть чтение файла в другой класс, и пусть там всё будет public, чтоб без сетов и гетов. Т.е. в основном классе нужно будет получить String переменную из класса для чтения с записанной в нее строкой и изменить её, ну и вывести на э кран. Пытался, но не получается. Помогите с этим разобраться, пожалуйста.

---

```
public class Read {

        String baseStringWithBlank = "";
        String encodedString = "";
        int numberOfStringsReaded = 0;
        String baseString = "";

        File f;

    Read(){
        f = new File("file.txt");
    }

    void Read(){

        try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(f), "Cp1251"))) {

            String readedString = "";
            while ((readedString = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                baseStringWithBlank += readedString;
                baseStringWithBlank += ";";
                numberOfStringsReaded++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        baseString = baseStringWithBlank.replaceAll(" ", "");
        System.out.println(baseString);
    }

        String GetContent(){
            return baseString;

    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Example {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

       // .........

        Read r = new Read();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStringsReaded; i++) {
            String parseCommand = baseString.substring(0, 3);

            String symbolAfterCommand = baseString.substring(3, 4);

            switch (parseCommand) {
                    case COMMAND_KOP:
                        encodedString += KOP;

//..........

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static final String MY_СONSTANT = "доступайся Clazz.MY_СONSTANT из любого места программы";
```

Answer (score 1):

String - неизменяемые объекты в Java, используйте StringBuilder или StringBuffer (в случае многопоточного исполнения кода).

Comment: @Rams666, хорошо. Как тогда через StringBuilder можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

[@compl](/users/19290/compl): Это хорошо, что вы хотите делегировать часть работы другому классу. Но плохо, что ваша архитектура требует публичного доступа одного класса к полям другого.

Попробуйте так:

1. Класс №1 (ответственный за чтение) получает в конструкторе имя файла. Он имеет метод `void Read()`, который выполняет чтение, и метод `List<String> GetContent()`, который возвращает все прочитанные строки.
2. Класс №2 — главная программа. Создаёт экземпляр класса №1, просит его прочитать файл, запрашивает результат и выводит его.

Публичные поля не понадобились.

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо. Вот, что получилось (см. вопрос). В классе Read вроде бы все понятно кроме последнего метода, т.е. как возвращать несколько String'ов? И еще, в главном классе я создал экземпляр класса, а дальше не совсем понимаю: просит его прочитать файл, запрашивает результат и выводит его.

Comment: @compl: Надо наверное немного по-другому: в класс `Read` добавьте `List<String> allStrings`, инициализируйте его в конструкторе, и добавляйте туда каждую прочитанную строку.

`GetContent` поменяйте на

    List<String> GetContent() {
        return allStrings;
    }

Comment: @compl: Тогда `Main` будет выглядеть так:

    Read read = new Read("file.txt"); // имя файла лучше передавать в конструкторе
    read.Read();
    for (String s : read.GetContent())) {
        // ...
    }

Comment: @VladD: получилось так:

`     allStrings.add(baseString);
        allStrings.add(encodedString);
    }

    List<String> GetContent() {
        return allStrings;
    }`

и

`read.Read();
        for (String s : read.GetContent()) {
            //этот момент не понял
        }`

Comment: @compl: А что именно непонятно? Обход в цикле списка строк.

Comment: @VladD: Да :) Не совсем понимаю.

Comment: @compl  А так?  
    List content =  read.GetContent();
    for(int i = 0; i<content.size; i++)
        String s = content.get(i);
        ...

Comment: @smackmychi, так а что вместо ... должно быть, я этого не понимаю.

Comment: @compl а что вы собрались делать при обходе списка строк? Этого вы не указали. Вам лишь показали как оформить чтение и возврат результата. Результат (список строк) хранится в данном случае в члене-данном allStrings. Метод GetContent возвращает allStrings. а for(String s:read.GetContent) - это цикл по элементам списка строк. А там уж вы сами решайте, чего собрались с каждой строкой делать (в данной записи цикла это переменная s).